# converting this query from SQL to mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

how can i achieve this query but using mongoose?

```
SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = "email@hotmail.com";
```

i want to find a password in the DB for a specified email, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query` to find the object you want and `projection` to return the desired value. Check [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

> **query**: Optional. Specifies selection filter using query operators. To return all documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty document ({}).

> **projection**: Optional. Specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter. To return all fields in the matching documents, omit this parameter

By the way you need something like this:

```
users.findOne({
  "email": "email@hotmail.com"
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "password": 1
})
```

The `query` is the first object, is like the `WHERE` in SQL. And `projection` the second object and is like `SELECT`, is where you say mongo "give me only the password field... and also don't give me `_id`" (by default _id is always given).

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L5EjHq9xVrF)

Note that in the query I've used `users.findOne` but it depends on your model name and the query you want.